# Create custom annotation that uses @JsonIgnore based on value in environment variable in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, java-annotations, annotation-introspector

I need to create a new annotation which is used to ignore a field in the output JSON file when the environment variable `var == false`. I tried to use `JsonAnnotationIntrospector`, but could not get the expected output.

```
public class Vehicle {
    String vehicle_name;
    String vehicle_model;
    //getters and setters  
    @MyAnnotation
    public String getVehicle_model() {
        return vehicle_model;
    }
}
```

Here I need to remove `vehicle_model` attribute when the environmental variable `var == false`.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@JsonIgnore
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

This is the declaration of my custom Annotation.
Can Someone tell me how should I write the Introspector part to get the functionality I need?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: My attempt at `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`

```
public class MyAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
@Override
public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(AnnotatedMember annotatedMember) {
    //need this part
   }
 }
```

And the implementation of `ObjectMapper` is

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(this);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}

public class Vehicle {

    private String vehicle_name;

    @MyAnnotation
    private String vehicle_model;
    //getters and setters

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {

            @Override
            public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(AnnotatedMember m) {

                if (!System.getenv("var").equals("true")) {
                    return false;
                }
                if(_findAnnotation(m, MyAnnotation.class) != null){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });

        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        vehicle.setVehicle_model("vehicle_model_value");
        vehicle.setVehicle_name("vehicle_name_value");

        String value = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(vehicle);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: HI, this works as equivalent to `@JsonIgnore`. I only want to remove a field from JSON file only if `System.getenv("var").equals("true");` Where should I write that check?

Comment: @Mr.Midnight  replace `if (_findAnnotation(m, MyAnnotation.class) == null)` with `if (!System.getenv("var").equals("true"))` ?

Comment: it works when `var` is `false`. But when `var` is `true`, `Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class Vehicle and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)`  PS: I have getters and setters

Comment: @Mr.Midnight Disabling it `objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)`  can solve the problem, but I don't know what will cause problems.

Comment: Well, the exception is gone. but the resulting JSON string is {}. Do we have to connect the MyAnnotation and the JacksonAnnotationIntrospector in any way?

Comment: `if (_findAnnotation(m, MyAnnotation.class) == null && !System.getenv("var").equals("true")) ` ?

Comment: It didn't work that way. But this worked  
`if (!System.getenv("var").equals("true")) { return false;}`
`if(_findAnnotation(m, MyAnnotation.class) != null){ return true;}`
`else{ return false;}`

Comment: Thank you and I can accept the answer if you edit it. :)

Comment: @Mr.Midnight If you know a better way, I would love to know.

Comment: Instead of returning `false` if your custom annotation is not found, you might call `return super.hasIgnoreMarker(m);` to make sure your mapper can still handle `@JsonIgnore` and other annotations.