# How to write a conditional @JsonIgnore

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to write an annotation that will ignore certain fields, but only in certain contexts.  I would love to be able to just inject a context value into ObjectMapper, but I can't find anything.  I need the serializing to work exactly the same using the default ObjectMapper.  But in a certain context, my annotation would take special action (in my case, the equivalent of `@JsonIgnore`).
I don't think filters would work for me, because it doesn't allow the default case to continue to work.  I also don't want to skip fields based on the property name.  I want any object to be able to be annotated with `@MyJsonIgnore`

Example

```
public class MyObject {
  private String field1 = "value1";
  @MyJsonIgnore
  private String field2 = "value2";
```

Normally, this would get serialized like this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(new MyObject());
{
   "field1": "value1",
   "field2": "value2"
}
```

But in my special use case, I would have

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setMagicalContext("context");
mapper.writeValueAsString(new MyObject());
{
   "field1": "value1"
}
```

`field2` would not get serialized since it has the `@MyJsonIgnore` annotation.

Is there anything that would do this?

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292845/create-custom-annotation-that-uses-jsonignore-based-on-value-in-environment-var

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me to JacksonAnnotationIntrospector, which I didn't know about